# How to sync clipboard in KDE Connect/Android 11?

Tags: android, clipboard, kde-connect

The very first feature listed on this app is:

```
Shared clipboard: copy and paste between your devices.
```

In Android 10, Google broke that feature and now the phone can receive clipboard contents from the desktop but not send them *to* the desktop. The developer appears to have a workaround as the release notes for 1.14 say:

- `Android 10: You can now send the clipboard contents via the notification`

but there's no hint *how* to do that, and the developer email on Google Play doesn't respond.

All of the plugins in the desktop app are turned on except `Send notifications` (which is for notifications in the opposite direction) and `Inhibit screensaver`.

In the android app, `All KDE Connect notifications` is On, `Persistent indicator` and `Allow notification dot` are off:

[image: notifications]

How do you "send the clipboard contents via the notification"?

Bruni's screenshot below is nothing like mine, but leads me to suspect I'm actually missing a plugin (There are actually no listed missing permissions).

[image]

Comment: I have the same or a similar issue. There is no "send clipboard", only "send files": https://i.imgur.com/fQ0VlhP.png

Comment: As long as you open both, the one on your PC and the one on your Android, and guarantee that they are connected, then, what you copied on your PC will automatically be copied to your Android.

Comment: @OChicken  That was never the problem. Copying PC -> Android has always worked, but Android decided to prevent copying clipboards in the other direction.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go to the Notifications of your Android device, find kde connect and click on send clipboard.

[image]

The screenshot is from the phone.
This is on KDE Connect 1.17, Android 11, KUbuntu 21.04, but I do not remember a time when it did not work on this phone and it came with android 10.

You need to allow KDE Connect to show notifications (on the phone)
[image]

Comment: Surely that's the desktop system. I don't want to send my clipboard **to** the phone, that Just Works. I want to send my clipboard **from** the phone to the desktop. If it **is** on the phone, then … are you saying I need to find that _every_ time I want something copied from my phone to my desktop? That's 80% of the functionality (for me) of KDE Connect gone :-(

Comment: You have to allow kdeconnect on the phone to push notifications (in the permissions of android).

Comment: @Auspex that is not the desktop system. It is my phone. this is the way to copy from the phone to the desktop. The reverse is indeed much easier.

Comment: @Auspex You can get used to it, but it is indeed more inconvinient. Unfortunately this is a design change in Android that is not possible to circumvent by kdeconnect developers. It would however probably work in the old way on a rooted android device.

Comment: No, I really don't think I can get used to it. I use KDE Connect to copy files quite irregularly, what I used to use it for _very_ frequently was to Copy my multi-factor authentication to the clipboard and then paste it into my desktop CLI. I definitely have permitted the phone to send notifications -- every time it connects to my desktop, I get a slew of notifications on the desktop -- but I see no option to send the clipboard.

Comment: This is strange. The option only shows up, when there is something in the clipboard. You have to allow kdeconnect (the android app) to show notifications **on the phone** is what i meant. The option to send the clipboard is on the notifications **on the android device**, not on the desktop.I will change the first screenshot to make clearer were you should look

Comment: And as I showed, KDE Connect is set to allow "All KDE Connect notifications". I don't get any option like that, and never have.

Comment: Perhaps you could use something like Tasker to periodically click the "send clipboard" notification text and so effectively automate clipboard syncing

Comment: @Auspex the "SEND CLIPBOARD" option is a part of the persistent indicator, which I can see in your screenshot that you have turned off. 
Enable the persistent indicator and you'll see "SEND CLIPBOARD" "SEND FILE" options in the persistent indicator. 

> You can now send the clipboard contents via the notification

here "the notification" is the persistent one.

Comment: @vyashole good catch.

Comment: @Paul I missed your comment (much) earlier. That's an interesting work-around!

Comment: Thanks @vyashole. That was indeed what I was missing. I _did_ say right in the question that the "persistent indicator" was off. And it was off because there isn't the slightest indication in the documentation that I would need it.

Answer (score 4):

To send clip from android to Desktop via KDE->

1. Select your text
2. click on share
   [screenshot, here for selecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diWtU.jpg)
3. Select KDE-Send to device
   [this screenshot for selecting KDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xCig.jpg)
4. Select the device to which you have to send
   [this ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlZDM.jpg)

Voila, it will open in the default editor of your desktop immediately.
This steps can also be performed to send any file to other device from android via KDE.

Although there is not any option to send it in KDE app, but the above steps are more faster(which we generally use to send anything) as we have not to  paste the clipboard in KDE app to send it and we can directly send it even without copying.

UPDATE: Now, in the latest android KDE app, there is option to send text directly through the remote input input option.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to manually change the Android keyboard to KDE Connect once. Afterwards you're able to pull the clipboard from your phone without additional user interaction.

Comment: In my opinion the discrepancy stems from the fact that there are two different questions in the original post:
1. Question in the title is solved by my solution: 'How to sync clipboard in KDE Connect/Android 11?' -> switch to KDE connect keyboard (the accepted answer doesn't provide a solution to this, since there's no "sync")
2. Question inside the text: 'How do you "send the clipboard contents via the notification"?' -> my answer is unrelated to this, that's what the accepted answer refers to

I don't mind removing my answer - but in that case the title of this questions needs change

Comment: This is absolutely an answer, as @Auspex argued. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have reported this as a bug: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=446366

This option should be available also in the list of commands for desktop devices.